# Why didn't the Amazons kill Steve during the beach fight?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-2017

In the recent *Wonder Woman* film Steve Trevor, an American spy, stumbles upon Themyscira whilst being pursued by German boats. On finding the island, the Germans attack the Amazons. A heavy exchange of fire takes place and the German soldiers are eventually overpowered.

I understand that when the battle had finished the Amazons decided to keep Steve alive and wrap him up in the whip in order to discover his intentions. But why didn't they kill him during the battle itself? Surely, as far as the Amazon were concerned at that point, all men were enemies. Only Diana really knew that he was any different from the Germans, and she didn't really have the time to tell the others.

**Shouldn't one of the many Amazon warriors have killed him during the battle?**

Comment: I think he was fairly obviously fighting alongside Diana.

Comment: Plot armor.  Also, perhaps they noticed he was shooting at the same people they were, and decided that for the time being he was worth keeping alive.

Comment: It'd be a really boring movie is the amazons killed the invaders and decided to stay on their island for the rest of eternity. Also, Diana wouldn't know what a... Erm.. Watch was.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that Steve was wearing a German uniform at the time. Which I didn't realize, *until one of the Amazons pointed it out*.

Comment: Didn't they try to raise their weapons to kill him after the battle and Diana steps in? Or am I completely mis-remembering that scene?

Comment: @TheIronCheek Yes, after the battle. I'm asking about during the battle.

Comment: When the battle first started, he was unarmed. I don't imagine the Amazonians would have killed an unarmed man unprovoked, they seem pretty honourable. He did pick up a rifle later, but by then they're in the midst of battle and he's shooting the attackers, so it probably wasn't worth the time and effort it would take to kill him.

Comment: Also, "all men were enemies"? I know Amazonians are wary of _all_ humans because of humanity's warmongering nature, but I don't recall them ever being sexist about it.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Well, the fact that they're men means that, by definition, that they're outsiders. Both the Germans and the Amazon seem pretty quick to jump to arms. Steve would be seen as an invader, especially as he was (as Dawooosh points out) he was wearing a German uniform at the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty simple: during the battle, the Amazons were attacking the people who were shooting at them. Steve wasn't shooting at them. Ergo, the Amazons didn't attack Steve.

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be a small flaw in the direction, because I wondered it too during viewing. But, on further thought, it must have been intended that the Amazons noticed he was effectively "with" Diana at that point. Or, at least, not charging at them with guns.